# Enabling the UIPickerView Control for ComboBox objects in Air for iOS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, uipickerview

I'm not sure if this is possible, but is it possible to enable the UIPickerView control native to iOS in an **Air for iOS** application (I'm designing in Flash CS6)?

I have several combo boxes that I have created in my AS3 document class, and the dropdown requires that the user clicks and holds on the (tiny) scroll bar to scroll through the list. I'd prefer that the user could gesture / touch scroll through the dropdown list of the combobox  - if integrating the UIPickerView control native to iOS is not possible, how would I achieve what I have described above?

**EDIT:** Just for anyone's future reference, I found this link: AS3 game gears has a wide array of Air Native extensions for iOS, Android etc. Here is an ANE for Native Dialog boxes in both Android and iOS: http://www.as3gamegears.com/air-native-extension/nativedialogs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going down the ANE route, if at all possible, I don't think is a wise route for you if you have no experience with Objective C.

I would suggest 2 other routes.

1. If you are sticking with the native Flash display have a search for Mad Components. There is a pickerList component that looks similar to the iOS pickers.
2. Alternatively you could look at using the Starling and Feathers frameworks to produce your pickers.

http://feathersui.com/examples/components-explorer/

Answer (score 1):

its possible with Adobe Native Extensions. Tutorial [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html)

Comment: And what Native Extension (.ANE) file would I add to enable integration of native iOS interfaces/controls? (Bear in mind I have no experience of iOS development apart from within Flash)

Comment: you have to develop it yourself, or have it developed by someone else. its a hard/tricky task.

Comment: Sounds like it. I've found a resource of Native Extensions online which I will include in an edit for any future wary travellers, but I'll probably just use crooksy88's answer above.